# WPF/Ribbon: Any control like color picker? How to create a simple 1?

Tags: wpf, ribbon

what control can i use to allow users to select color.

or else how would a simple one be created. since this is just a practice project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest drop of the open source [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ColorPicker&referringTitle=Home) project out on CodePlex includes a color picker. If you are using .NET 4.0 I would recommend giving it a try.

Answer (score -1):

I don't fully understand what do You mean by "allow user to select color" so two i have two solutions for You.

First You can use the color dialog for color selection

```
ColorDialog colorDialog = new ColorDialog(); 
if ( colorDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel )
{ 
   textBox.ForeColor = colorDialog.Color;
}
```

or get familiar with this sample [ColorPicke Custome Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771620.aspx)

Comment: oh this is 1 option. its uses windows forms i think. i need to add reference to System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Yes it is from that namespace